# Adjective meaning "like someone else?"

Tags: adjectives

**Example in this case:** "experiencing _____ speech"

**More specifically:** "She shouted with a deep voice, *a voice not her own*."

Comment: Have you googled schizophrenia?  Does anything in anything you have read suggest a word, and if so, why is that word not what you are looking for?  For example, I came up with "delusional" in less than 30 seconds.  Maybe not the right word, but it would be helpful to people who are trying to answer your question if you did a bit of work on it first.

Comment: I could not find any similar words.

Comment: Read my above edit. I removed anything about mental disorder.

Comment: New edit. Check above.

Comment: "alien voice"; Actually, I like your second sentence.  Not everything can be expressed in one word in English.

Comment: The word you're looking for may be *uncharacteristic*.

Comment: I think adjectives like ***copying***, ***copy-*** *noun*, or ***imitative*** are worth considering.

Answer (score -2):

If such a condition were ever proven, the clinical term would likely become *dissociative aphasia.*

[Dissociation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(psychology)) refers to the psychological divorcing of oneself from one's actions, the so-called splitting of a personality from one's true self.

[Aphasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(neuropsychology)#Examples_of_double_dissociations) refers to the loss of the power to speak for oneself.

Combined, it would mean the loss of the ability to speak for oneself due to dissociation or a dissociative condition, losing the power of speech to that dissociated self that was doing the speaking during the fugue state.

Comment: I don't think dissociative aphasia would convey that meaning. *Dissociative aphasia* would most likely be construed as the incapability to name certain objects/word classes but not others (see [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0093934X01925362)), or differences in performance between spoken vs written language (see [this](http://bcn.iums.ac.ir/files/site1/user_files_c424bc/admin-A-10-1-104-a992974.pdf)), to name a few examples. That is to say, *dissociative aphasia* alludes to selective impairment, not to "speaking like someone else".

Comment: I got influenza that resulted in such severe encephalitis that I lost the ability to speak.  It took me a year of speech therapy to be fully able to speak again, to not switch words, to resolve a sequencing disorder that resulted.  I'm well aware of what aphasia is.  I also know that it applies differently in different contexts.  Like in the sources I provided, the term is used for being unable to speak for various reasons.  If the "true self" is unable to speak because another personality is in charge, that is very much like the neurological double aphasia described in the source material.

Comment: I'm truely sorry to hear that, but I've never heard aphasia used in such a way as what the OP described. The sources provided link to the Wikipedia, which isn't much of an authority. The thing is that you are coining a new term, which isn't justified here because (1) the term used already exists, (2) there are no references as to whether what is being described *already* has a name (I believe it's just split personality) and (3) there's no way to know how others will interpret it. Coining new terms at will is a good think in literature, not in science.